# We're all Rebecca Chernoff \o/

Tags: discussion, fun, april-fools

On this [frabjous day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Fools%27_Day), our community manager [Rebecca Chernoff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140548/rebecca-chernoff) has graciously [allowed all of us](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/588300#588300) <sup>*1</sup> to be her for one day, and one day only. And so, ladies and gentlemen, let me present to you:

> #### [We're all Rebecca Chernoff \o/](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1722364/Stack%20Overflow/We%27re%20all%20Rebecca%20Chernoff.user.js)

A userscript dedicated to making all of you Rebecca Chernoffs. Really, give ourselves a pat on the back, we all deserve to be Rebecca Chernoff. Even if it's just for a day.

[image: \o/]

<sup>**Fine print:** The userscript runs on MSO and MSO chat (doesn't quite work 100% on chat, but will fix that later). Any headaches/insanity caused by overexposure to Rebecca Chernoff is your own problem. Installation instructions can be found on the Stack Apps [script tag wiki](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/script). Tested on Firefox 4 and Chrome beta.</sup>

---

<sup>*1</sup> For future references, `rchern('no') === 'yes'`

Comment: You had me at no = yes.

Comment: I hope you get Taxonomist for the `rebecca-chernoff` tag

Comment: oy, seriously?!

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff: no == yes is a fundamental truth of the universe! @RebeccaChernoff: I'd lol if he did. @RebeccaChernoff: Yes, seriously. :P

Comment: `Oh we can be Heroes, just for one day`

Comment: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/589498#589498

Answer (score 33):

[Oy.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/70807#70807)

Comment: .......... Vey.

Answer (score 24):

(:

Answer (score 21):

Malkovich, Malkovich, Malkovich

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q6Fuxkinhug

Comment: I just watched *Being John Malkovich* in sepia. http://i.imgur.com/ng1xq.png

Answer (score 12):

Userscripts?  Usercripts!  We don't need no stinkin' userscripts!

Comment: You know you can't change names again for 30 days, right? :)

Comment: @RBemrose I believe in *miracles!*

Comment: @RBemrose you know he knows devs and they have powers right? You know there's a secondary "name-change" that you can use right? 1337 skills alright ;)