# Is it possible to browse a chatroom under invisible mode?

Tags: feature-request, chat

E.g. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2496/academia

I know that I can browse the chat when I'm not logged on. But what if I am logged on and want to spare the inconvenience of logging off/multiple browsers?

Comment: Use an incognito window?

Comment: This isn't something we currently have planned, mainly since it seems such a rare case, and there are multiple ways of achieving this simply,and quickly (@Zoredache hits the nail pretty squarely). Is there a particular scenario you have in mind that needs this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of jumping into the chatroom, you can view the transcript. In this example, the transcript is at https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2496.

Reading the transcript does not count you as entering the room. While it will not update in real time, every time you refresh will update the transcript for any new messages. Not the most efficient means, but otherwise, there isn't any other means of silently observing a room in-engine.

Comment: [Jinx](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123136/168428)!

Answer (score 14):

Well, you can always [monitor the transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2496). It doesn't refresh automatically, but if you're not looking to be an active participant in the chat I'm not sure why this would be an issue.

Otherwise, just open a private browsing session in your browser of choice where you won't be logged into the Stack Exchange network, and access the room that way. It's a little extra work on your part, but this seems like an odd use case to me anyway.

Comment: [Jinx](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123137/168428)!

Comment: Actually @jadarnel27, Grace Note is Tim's sockpuppet account.

Comment: Yeah, but Tim is just rchern's sockpuppet.

Comment: It always leads back to everyone being Rebecca Chernoff.  Spooky ^_^

Comment: That is true @GraceNote. But wo *isn't* rchern's sockpuppet? rchern is an agent of this system, she can control any user who hasn't taken the red pill!

Comment: @jadarnel27: Why's that?

Comment: @BoltClock You don't think it would be spooky if we were [all the same person](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85591/were-all-rebecca-chernoff-o)?