# Spectator mode on chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

I like the chat feature and I am one of the regular users for it. The thing is, sometimes I love to read what guys talk about in a chat room, but without being visible to them usually to avoid pings  (we have a very good chat community in Travel.SE). Currently I open another browser where I am not logged in and open the chat there to see it without appearing. I also can load the transcript but that requires me to refresh.

Is there a way to be a spectator in a chat room (your name not in the users list) and without being logged out? If not can that be done?

Note: There is a [3 years old request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123132/is-it-possible-to-browse-a-chatroom-under-invisible-mode) which suggested the transcript, which is not a practical solution IMO. So I am reviving that request again hoping it will get attention.