# Would it be a violation of StackOverflow if I created a custom flair?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation, flair

I noticed you can't really customize the 'flair' image for StackOverflow

With CSS or a variety of their defaults. Don't get me wrong I think they're fine but I was asked if you could create your own?

If I was to go about doing this I would parse out the information from a users page ex.

> https://stackoverflow.com/users/422312/

```
jQuery or another language would look for the hlinks-user id
then it would parse out the different badges and reputation
```

EDIT:

So lets say I use the API (parsing seems a little hacky anyways) by just taking the user data and displaying it on say someones blog wouldn't be a violation?

Their might be another way etc but this is the one that was fresh on my mind. So is it a violation?

Comment: Let's just talk to @RebeccaChernoff about revamping the flair system. ^_^ Oh Ms. Rebecca!

Comment: @animuson Is it sad I don't know who that is?

Comment: A violation of what? Trademark, copyright, terms of service? You can't violate a website.

Comment: Did you take a look at [the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs)? Scraping and parsing the user's page doesn't seem right.

Comment: @TimYiJiang I was trying to include any of them. :P And yes I have seen the API.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Totally.

Penalties for committing this grave transgression range from complete indifference to [employment](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/welcome-valued-associate-rebecca-chernoff/):

> In addition to writing a whole bunch of [useful userscripts](https://github.com/rchern/StackExchangeScripts) for Stack Exchange sites and chat, Rebecca also worked extensively with [the Stack Exchange API](https://stackapps.com/) to build [StackFlair](http://stackflair.com/).

Proceed at your own risk.

You *should* use [the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) to get the information you need though, since that's kind of what it's there for.

Comment: So lets say I use the API (parsing seems a little hacky anyways) by just taking the user data and displaying it on say someones blog wouldn't be a violation?

Comment: Should be fine, @Nate. Obviously, you should be respectful - [both of us](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance), and the folks you're creating flair for. But otherwise, this is sort of why the API exists - so that folks can make use of the data elsewhere.

Comment: Of course, I wouldn't want to take away any accomplishment or work credited to someone else. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it!

Comment: So you're saying the only real penalty is rchern's wrath? **BRING IT!**

Comment: Oh no, @casper... The real penalty is *becoming* rchern! *Battle not with rchern, lest ye become rchern, and if you gaze into the API, the API gazes also into you...*

Comment: [We are all Rebecca Chernoff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85591/were-all-rebecca-chernoff-o). [meta-tag:status-completed]

Comment: Just out of curiosity @Shog9 Why does the link have a tooltip of "...and she was never heard from again..."

Comment: All good punishments end that way, @Nate. Abruptly.

Comment: @Shog9 Uh I see. Well thanks again!

Comment: Stackflair link is down