# Issue with image alternate text in blog authors page

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, blog, alt-text

There is an issue with the `<img alt` in the [Stack Overflow Blog - Authors page](https://stackoverflow.blog/authors/).

Today when I'm accessing the blog authors page in slow internet connection, I see the image alternate text is displaying as "Avatar for Aarthi Devanathan" for most of the user images.

> [image: Slow connection]

After inspect the element for all the users div, I can see the following text is set to the `<img` tag:

```
<img alt="Avatar for Aarthi Devanathan" ...
```

> [image: img alt issue]

As [Aarthi](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/165582/aarthi) is a former Stack Exchange employee, may be their profile is removed from the authors page, but due to some copy & paste, the alternate text is applied to all other users.

Comment: [We're all Aarthi Devanathan](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85591/were-all-rebecca-chernoff-o). ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed, thank you. It was pulling the first name from the author list and using it everywhere!

Comment: Very quick fix, Thank you :)

Comment: Um.  Doesn't this mean you're showing screen reader users: "Avatar for Abby T. Mars Abby T. Mars Director of Community Management"?  In other words, isn't the correct practice to use `<img alt=""` here?  Should I write a new FR post to ask this?

Comment: Awesome! As a side note, why some of the authors don't have avatars? Because it only support Gravatar and they have imgur hosted avatar only? In that case, any chance to fix it? I like to see face attached to names. :)

Comment: @Shadow9 perhaps they don't want their face there.

Comment: @Luuklag nah, Nick love to show his face. ;)